# Drupal content in Solr

Tags: xml, drupal, solr, drupal-7, lucene

I am using **Apache Solr Search** module for my **Drupal 7** website. I have Solr running on a different server, my Drupal website is successfully connected to it and it works great meaning when I search for some text that is part of the Drupal website content such as 'basic page' or 'article', it returns search results. All good!

However, **I have some xml documents(external data) that I want to be part of this search in the Drupal website**. I have indexed those xml documents directly in Solr and they are searchable through Solr Admin only. I want to make them searchable from the Drupal website as well which shares the same Solr instance. How can I achieve that?

Do I have to modify schema.xml in Solr that was replaced with the one packaged from Drupal -apache solr module? Please shed some light.

Comment: If you search for the indexed xml files, what do you got in return?

Comment: If you use Open Solr you could consider copying the schema.xml from the Search API Solr module to Open Solr, but its compatibility with 4.x is not stable.

Comment: @balintpekker: when i search for indexed xml files in Drupal search powered by Solr, it does not return anything. "Your search yielded no results"

Comment: but when I search for drupal article or basic page text, it does return results.

Comment: I am thinking may be mapping should be done to match xml document fields to drupal - solr schema fields?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to do what you're describing with the stock Apache Solr module alone. The closest contrib module I know of is the [Apache Solr Attachments](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr_attachments) module, but my understanding is that the attachments would need to be associated with content rather than indexed externally.

That said, there is an [Apache Solr Examples](https://www.drupal.org/project/apachesolr_examples) project that includes a submodule called [Apache Solr external index](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/apachesolr_examples/tree/apachesolr_external_index?h=7.x-1.1) that is described as, "An example of how to search an external index with Solr." There may be enough there to help you create a custom module to do what you're needing.